# Using Scheme to assign the value returned by a function to a variable in another function

Tags: scheme, guile

I have a function remove_duplicates that removes the duplicates in a list and returns the new list.

```
(define (remove_duplicate list)
(cond
    ((null? list) '() )

    ;member? returns #t if the element is in the list and #f otherwise
    ((member? (car list) (cdr list)) (remove_duplicate(cdr list)))

    (else (cons (car list) (remove_duplicate (cdr list))))

))
```

I want to assign the return value from this function call to a variable in another function f.

```
(define (f list)
    ;I have tried this syntax and various other things without getting the results I would like
    (let* (list) (remove_duplicates list))
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for using `let`:

```
(define (f lst)
  (let ((list-without-dups (remove_duplicates lst)))
    ; here you can use the variable called list-without-dups
    ))
```

Also notice that it's a bad idea to name `list` a parameter and/or a variable, that clashes with a built-in procedure with the same name.